# PostgreSQL- insert result of query into exisiting table, auto-increment id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created an empty table with the following SQL statement. My understanding (based on this tutorial: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-serial/) was that `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` will automatically provide an auto-incremented id for every new row:

```
CREATE TABLE "shema".my_table
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    transaction text NOT NULL,
    service_privider text NOT NULL,
    customer_id text NOT NULL,
    value numeric NOT NULL        
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE "shema".my_table
    OWNER to admin;
```

Now I am querying another tables and would like to save the result of that query into `my_table`. The result of the query outputs following schema:

```
transaction 
service_provider 
customer_id 
value
```

meaning the schema of `my_table` minus `id`. when I try to execute:

```
INSERT into my table
Select {here is the query}
```

Then I am getting an error that   `column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type text`. I interpret it that the sql query is looking for `id` column and cannot find it. How can I insert data into `my_table` without explicitly stating `id` number but have this `id` auto-generated for every row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always mention the columns you want to INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO schemaname.my_table("transaction", service_privider, customer_id, value)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?;
```

If you don't, your code will break now or somewhere in the future.

By the way, transaction is a reserved word, try to use a better column name.